# printing table data in multiple pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: data table]

How do i print the above table data in two pages based on ***group*** types seperately? Can this be achieved with `window.print` and some css and javascript tweaks?

Any idea/suggestion are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, when the table switches from a ***group*** of "Teddy Bear" to "Baby Bear" you want this on a new page?

If so, then structure the table with separate `<thead>` and `<tbody>` sections, like so:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr class="pageBreak">
            <th>Child</th>
            <th>Group</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Alberto</td>
            <td>Teddy Bear</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Guadalupe</td>
            <td>Teddy Bear</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Carlos</td>
            <td>Baby Bear</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Oswaldo</td>
            <td>Baby Bear</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Notice that different groups are in different `<tbody>`s.

Then you can use CSS like:

```
tbody {page-break-after:always;}
```

And the groups will print on separate pages, plus in most browsers, the headers will be repeated.

Print or print preview [this example at jsBin](http://jsbin.com/usotah).

Comment: the problem is that my code doesn't creates multiple `tbody`. Isn't there's other way to achieve beside `tbody`. many thanx.

Comment: Yes, there must be a dozen other ways, but using `thead` and multiple `tbody`s is the best route as it: (1) is semantically correct, (2) doesn't require the user to have javascript, (3) is more robust, (4) actually requires the *least* (re)programming effort. ... You're going to have to change or add to your code no matter what.  Better to make a smallish change, server-side, than try to kludge around it in the user's browser.